# How should I store employee data with Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am setting up a new company and we are using Azure AD. We are remote-first and cloud-only. We do not and will not have an on-premises Active Directory controller.

How is it recommended to store employee data such as birthday, hire date, and social security number? It is unclear how to extend the schema. When I try to fetch a birth date using the Graph API, I get "Error message: This operation target is not yet supported.". When I extend the schema using "External Identities -> Custom User Attributes", I don't see a way to edit those inside the Azure AD portal.

My administrative interface is a Java application built using the Microsoft Graph API. It works fine for the standard fields (e.g., displayName, givenName, surname, etc.).

I am currently integrated with a PostgreSQL database in Azure using the authentication that works against the Azure AD API. That works fine and I can put employee metadata there, but is is not clear if I should.

Answer (score 1):

Using AAD Connect you can flow an extension attribute from AD to the MV attribute employeeHireDate which will export successfully to AAD.

Make sure your extension attribute uses Generalized-Time syntax. These dates are strings in the format "YYYYMMDDhhmmss.0Z".
Then create an inbound sync rule to populate employeeHireDate
[image: Flow Rule]

This will flow to AAD. This was completed with AAD Connect Version: 2.1.16.0

Answer (score 0):

We can store the employee data like birthday and hire date in azure AD through couple of ways.
One way is to use azure ad connect (if you have on premise active directory) and the other way is using schema extensions. You need to use Microsoft Graph API to work with azure ad schema extension, there is no direct option to extend the schema from azure portal.

Please follow the steps in this doc to [Create schemaExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Schema extensions are supported for following resource types.

1.contact

2.device

3.event on a user or Microsoft 365 group calendar

4.post of a Microsoft 365 group

5.group

6.message

7.organization

8.user [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Here is the  reference article written by @Toni PohI, About Azure AD schema extension [Working with Azure AD schema extensions and Microsoft Graph](https://blog.atwork.at/post/Azure-AD-schema-extensions-and-Microsoft-Graph)